# Tratar valores monetários R$ XX,YY M / B / K em pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Estou tratando dados de um dataframe que vem com valores com virgulas e % com virgulas, segue exemplos que já estão funcionando:

```py
    # Substituir porcentagens com vírgula por floats
    # 10,08%, 1,06%
    df = df.replace(r'^(\d{1,2}),(\d{1,2})%$', r'\1.\2', regex=True)
    # 10,08, 1,06
    df = df.replace(r'^(\d{1,2}),(\d{1,2})$', r'\1.\2', regex=True)
    # R$ 10,74, R$ 9,46, R$ 166,00
    df = df.replace(r'^R\$ (\d+),(\d+)$', r'\1.\2', regex=True)
    # R$ 2.002,05
    df = df.replace(r'^R\$ (\d+).(\d+),(\d+)$', r'\1\2.\3', regex=True)
```

Gostaria de resolver números que contem casas com virgula más também contem letras indicando K, M, B para mil, milhoes, e bilhoes, ex:

```
R$ 99,27 K  
R$ 8,80 M   
R$ 117,25 K 
...
```

Ao final cheguei a esse código:

```py
# R$ 274,71 K -> 27471
df = df.replace(r'^R\$ (\d+).(\d+) K$', r'\1\2', regex=True)
```

Gostaria de adicionar os zeros ao final, ou multiplicar, já tentei adicionar o \000 ou \0 etc ao final do replace mas sem sucesso.

```py
df= df.replace(r'^R\$ (\d+).(\d+) K$', r'\1\2\000', regex=True)
```

Qualquer ajuda sera bem vinda, obrigado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Parece que voce esta tentando remover os caracteres "R$:, espaçaos em branco a letra indicadora (K, M, B) dos valores no formato "R$ X,XX K" e converte-los em numeros inteiros multiplicando-os pelo fator adequado. Para adicionar os zeros no final, voce pode utilizar a funçao str.zfill() apos fazer a substituiçao. Aqui esta um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
import pandas as pd

# Exemplo de dataframe com os valores
data = {'LIQUIDEZ_DIARIA': ['R$ 99,27 K', 'R$ 8,80 M', 'R$ 117,25 K']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Mapeamento dos fatores para cada letra indicadora
fatores = {'K': 1_000, 'M': 1_000_000, 'B': 1_000_000_000}

# Função para converter os valores
def converter_valor(valor):
    valor = valor.replace('R$', '')  # Remover 'R$'
    valor = valor.replace(' ', '')  # Remover espaços em branco
    letra = valor[-1]  # Último caractere é a letra indicadora
    numero = float(valor[:-1].replace(',', '.'))  # Converter para float
    fator = fatores[letra]  # Obter o fator adequado
    valor_inteiro = int(numero * fator)  # Converter para inteiro multiplicando pelo fator
    return str(valor_inteiro).zfill(5)  # Adicionar zeros no final

# Aplicar a função ao dataframe
df['LIQUIDEZ_DIARIA'] = df['LIQUIDEZ_DIARIA'].apply(converter_valor)

print(df['LIQUIDEZ_DIARIA'])
```

os saida sera:

```
0      99270
1    8800000
2     117250
Name: LIQUIDEZ_DIARIA, dtype: object
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado! Sim isso funciona para coluna específica, porém eu gostaria de fazer para o DF inteiro, sem especificar a coluna.

Comment: Ola @Collaxd ! É claro que você poderia, por exemplo, fazer um loop `for column in df.columns: df[column] = df[column].apply(converter_valor)`